# creating a function that calculates frequency between dates with conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, for-loop

I want to write a function that takes two conditions with Dates. This is how it goes: Lets say i have two dates, DATE1 = 30-06-2018 and DATE2 = 30-12-2019, and a variable called frequency (it can be 6 or 4 or 1).

I need to calculate the frequency dates in between those two DATE1 and DATE2 . If frequency is 6, the DATE1 should be added for 6 months until it is not greater than DATE2 i.e,

```
if frq == 6:
            Date_11 = DATE1 + relativedelta(months=+6)
            Date_12 = Date_11 + relativedelta(months=+6)
            Date_13 = Date_12 + relativedelta(months=+6)
            Print(date_11,date_12,date_13)
```

You can see that I am stopping with Date_13, because it can't go more than that. Because Date_13 needs to less than DATE2. And if frequency is 4, i should add every 4 months,

```
if frq == 4:
            Date_11 = DATE1 + relativedelta(months=+4)
            Date_12 = Date_11 + relativedelta(months=+4)
            Date_13 = Date_12 + relativedelta(months=+4)
            Date_14 = Date_13 + relativedelta(months=+4)
            Print(date_11,date_12,date_13,date_14)
```

And here I am stopping with Date_14 because Date_15 will be greater than DATE2.

Can someone suggest me how i can write this a one loop using if and for along with two conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a generator function and a while loop to achieve this.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def _convert_to_date_time_object(date_):
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(date_, '%d-%m-%Y').date()


def yield_date_in_between_range(date_one_in_str, date_two_in_str, frequency_):
    # Convert input date string into python date time object.
    date_one, date_two = map(_convert_to_date_time_object,                       
                            [date_one_in_str, date_two_in_str])

    # Add month and check whether if it exceeds more than limit.
    date_one = date_one + relativedelta(months=+frequency_)
    if date_one >= date_two:
        raise StopIteration
    while date_one < date_two:
        yield date_one
        date_one = date_one + relativedelta(months=+frequency_)
```

**Demo**

```
>> input_date_one = "30-06-2018"
>> input_date_two = "30-12-2019"
>> frequency = 6

>> print(list(yield_date_in_between_range(input_date_one, input_date_two, frequency)))
>> ['30-12-2018', '30-06-2019']

>> input_date_one = "30-06-2018"
>> input_date_two = "30-07-2018"
>> frequency = 6

>>print(list(yield_date_in_between_range(input_date_one, input_date_two, frequency)))
>> []
```